# How to use Least Squares method to extact line from laser scans datas?

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello

I would like extract lines from my laser scans data. So I find that Hough Transform can do that but maybe the easiest way is the Least Squares method. So any help of implementation of Least Squares method in ROS/C++??

Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/66578/how-to-use-least-squares-method-to-extact-line-from-laser-scans-datas??/) by [Astronaut](https://answers.ros.org/users/2221/astronaut/) on ROS Answers with karma: 330 on 2013-07-03

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I've seen a lot of academic papers submitted on this topic - there are also many other places online to find a Houghs Transform  or Least Squares algorithm. I'd suggest you start looking elsewhere online - I don't think this is the best place for that kind of question.

---

Originally posted by [asriraman93](https://answers.ros.org/users/5035/asriraman93/) with karma: 75 on 2013-07-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Astronaut](https://answers.ros.org/users/2221/astronaut/) on 2013-07-03**:
ok. I saw online lots of C++ code of Least square and Hough Transform , only was not sure how to implement that on ROS .. Thanks anyway